# Observer pattern - How to handle persistence of observed and observers objects

Tags: database, spring-boot, orm, observer-pattern

Using observer pattern, at some point in the application there is a `Object A` that notify some `Observers objects` when its state changes. So this happened while the application was used:

1. `Object A` was created.
2. `Observers objects` were created and registered to be notified when `Object A` state changes.

But when the application restart, I need again this `Object A` to exist and the `Observers objects` to be notified about state changes. I dont know how this situation is commonly handled. I can persist the `Object A` and `Observers` in database, and I can persist also the relationship, then using a `ORM`:

1. `Object A` is retrieved from database (with `observers`) using `ORM`.
2. If `Object A` is changed, then its `observers` are notified and do its stuff.

Above solution means everytime `observers` of `Obsect A` are registered/unregistered, relationship between `Object A` and `observers` should be updated in persistence. Also means that Observers `equals` and `hashcode` method should be overrided because when unregistering a `observer` we get the `Object A` from database (so its a new `Object` and also the `Observers` are new objects) so we use the state and not its address to identify them.

Other solution could be load the observed and observers objects in memory (and register the `observers`) when the application initializes and having them in cache in the `ORM`.

Which design is better or commonly used?